# Find the symmetric matrix which maps one vector to another

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am searching a way to calculate the matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ for given two vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $Ax = y$.

I think normally I would need 3 pairs $(x_i, y_i)$ with $i = 1,2,3$ to solve this problem by defining two matrices $X = (x_1, x_2, x_3), Y=(y_1, y_2, y_3)$ and solve $A = XY^{-1}$.

In my case I know my matrix $A$ is symmetric. Is this condition enough to get a solution with only one pair? If yes how? And if not, what else could I do?

Comment: It's not enough, for example $x = y = (1, 0, 0)$, any diagonal A with an one in $A_{11}$ will do (and all of them are symmetric).

Comment: Thank you! I know that in general I would need 3 vector pairs. Does the symmetry somehow reduce this requirement?

Comment: I just gave you an example. Diagonal matrices are symmetric, yet you still need 3 independent vectors.

Answer (score 2):

If there was a way to do this, $M(3,\mathbb R)$ would act transitively on $\mathbb R^3$, but it does not. Take e.g. $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$, you will not find any $A$ that works.

Comment: Therefore I uses the capital letter $Y$ which I defined as a matrix i.e. $Y = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$,  where each $y_i$  is a vector.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, then fine.

Comment: Oh wait, I think you missunderstood my notation. Let $y_1, y_2, y_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$. I define the matrix $Y:=(y_1| y_2| y_3)$ as a $3\times 3$ matrix, where each column $i$ is the vector $y_i$.

Comment: Yes I did, I already commented on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to figure out if we can get a closed form for a symmetric $A$ such that $Ax=y$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n.$ So here is my best attempt to answer this myself.

Notation: Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
\vdots \\
x_n  
\end{bmatrix}$, $y=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
\vdots \\
y_n  
\end{bmatrix}$

We want so determine the entries of a symmetric matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a_{1n} & a_{2n} & \dots & a_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

For In general, we get equations that look like $y_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_i,$ where  $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$.

Then for the $n=3$ case, we have that

$$ a_{11}=\frac{y_1 -a_{12}x_1 -a_{13}x_1}{x_1}$$
$$ a_{22}=\frac{y_2 -a_{12}x_2 -a_{23}x_2}{x_2}$$
$$ a_{33}=\frac{y_3 -a_{13}x_3 -a_{33}x_3}{x_3}$$  and $a_{ij}$ are all free variables for $i\neq j$.